# Control Access to Class Members

Tags: c#, class

I want a specific routine to be able to set a variable within a class - but the field otherwise to remain read-only.

For example the int 'authlevel' here should be publicly accessible to read - but only able to be set by selective subs;

```
public class SessionAuth
{
    int authLevel;
    public int AuthLevel
    {
        get
            {return authLevel;}

        set
            {<<IF CALLER = SUB XYZ>> then authLevel=value;}

    }
  ...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: As written, these are endless loops. E.g. the get method calls the get method, which calls the get method, ...

Comment: That's a fair point - i'm really not very good....

Comment: Usually you do this by exposing getters in public interfaces, and then having internal classes which have internal setters for these properties. This restricts the setter to internal library members only, while other libraries know only about the readonly interface.

Comment: Side note: DanB - please avoid greetings/thank you notes in the post. I've updated your code also to remove infinite recursion - for future posts edit your post in addition to answering to comments (thanks for prompt responses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably *could* do this via the diagnostic libraries (that are used to generate call stacks), but you don't want to.

If you need to restrict access to the setter, mark it as `private` so that only your class can modify it. If you can't trust your own class, you need to re-think your code and design.

```
public int MyProp { get; private set; }
```

Comment: The more pertinent question is whether I can trust my own coding ;) Thanks for the response.

Comment: @DanB Yes, if you can't trust your own class, well, you have bigger problems ;) Glad I was able to help. Note that `protected` and `internal` can also help protect members.